# Apache 400 bad request, Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring.so'

Tags: php, ubuntu

The apache error log shows:

> [Tue Feb 13 09:53:19.292366 2018] [suexec:notice] [pid 13643:tid
> 140586989283072] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper:
> /usr/local/apache/bin/suexec)
>
> [Tue Feb 13 09:53:19.292473 2018]
> [:notice] [pid 13643:tid 140586989283072] ModSecurity for Apache/2.9.2
> (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
>
> [Tue Feb 13 09:53:19.292479
> 2018] [:notice] [pid 13643:tid 140586989283072] ModSecurity: APR
> compiled version="1.6.3"; loaded version="1.6.3"
>
> [Tue Feb 13
> 09:53:19.292483 2018] [:notice] [pid 13643:tid 140586989283072]
> ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.41 "; loaded version="8.41
> 2017-07-05"
>
> [Tue Feb 13 09:53:19.292487 2018] [:notice] [pid 13643:tid
> 140586989283072] ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.9.3"
>
> [Tue Feb 13 09:53:19.292490 2018] [:notice] [pid 13643:tid 140586989283072]
> ModSecurity: Status engine is currently disabled, enable it by set
> SecStatusEngine to On.
>
> [Tue Feb 13 09:53:19.358205 2018] [ssl:warn]
> [pid 13644:tid 140586989283072] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not
> configured [hint: SSLSessionCache] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable
> to load dynamic library 'mbstring.so' (tried:
> /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20170718/mbstring.so
> (/usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20170718/mbstring.so:
> cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory),
> /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20170718/mbstring.so.so
> (/usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20170718/mbstring.so.so:
> cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown
> on line 0
>
> [Tue Feb 13 09:53:19.383462 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid
> 13644:tid 140586989283072] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Unix)
> OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations [Tue Feb 13
> 09:53:19.383522 2018] [core:notice] [pid 13644:tid 140586989283072]
> AH00094: Command line: '/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd'

And when i type `php -m`

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring.so' (tried: /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20170718/mbstring.so (/usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20170718/mbstring.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20170718/mbstring.so.so (/usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20170718/mbstring.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
enchant
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmagick
gmp
hash
iconv
imagick
imap
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
//more
```

As you can see there is mbstring among the list.
And I also did sudo apt-get install php-mbstring.
It updated nothing.
My php version is 7.0.25, using Ubuntu 16.04 64 Bit. Can anyone know how to solve the problem?

Comment: try to using this command php -i | grep ini

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have an empty "extension =" line in /usr/local/lib/php.ini file:

```
grep extension /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

Basically, the extension line would have no content after the equals sign. If such a line does exist, comment out the empty extension line and restart Apache.

Refer: [cPanel forum](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-no-debug-non-zts.207682/)

Comment: At last I re-install php to solve this problem, I tried the common solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you're running is looking for a package that doesn't exist in the configured paths (mbstring.so means "mbstring shared object" which would be a linux library).

It's not clear from your answer whether you actually have mbstring installed.

You can try running the following to verify that you have what you need installed:

```
$ sudo apt-cache search mbstring
```

For me I get:

```
php-mbstring - MBSTRING module for PHP [default]
php-patchwork-utf8 - UTF-8 strings handling for PHP
php-symfony-polyfill-mbstring - Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension
php-symfony-polyfill-util - Symfony utilities for portability of PHP codes
php7.1-mbstring - MBSTRING module for PHP
```

Then try installing either of the mbstring packages and let us know what you get.

Comment: At last I re-install php to solve this problem, I tried the common solution though.